# Aumentar 10% a una compra en C

Tags: c, condiciones

Hola soy nuevo en la programación, hice este pequeño código que me funciona pero ¿cómo puedo agregar al programa (o sea que haga las dos operaciones en el mismo programa) que si el precio ingresado es menor a 5000 en vez de restar se lo aumente?
Muchísimas gracias

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float precio;
    printf("Ingrese el monto de la compra: \n");
    scanf("%f", &precio);

    if (precio>5000)
      precio=precio-(precio*0.10);
    printf("El monto final es de %f", precio);
}
```

Comment: Hola estimado, lo que tu necesitas es saber el uso y aplicación de las sentencias condicionales **if**, **else** e **if else**, estas te permiten hacer justo lo que quieres, puedes leer sobre eso [aquí](https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/C++/Condicionales/Condicional-if-else)
El uso básico es
`if(condicional){ #TODO}else{ #TODO}`
En donde el **if** va a ejecutarse cuando tu condicional sea verdadera y el **else** va a hacer lo que se ejecuta cuando esa condicional no se cumpla

Answer (score 3):

Es muy simple, solo agrega la sentencia `else` a tu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float precio;
    printf("Ingrese el monto de la compra: \n");
    scanf("%f", &precio);

    if (precio>5000)
        precio=precio-(precio*0.10);
    else
        precio=precio+(precio*0.10);
    
    printf("El monto final es de %f", precio);
}
```

Nota que ahora, si el precio no es mayor a 5000 se ejecutará el `else`, que en lugar de restarlo lo aumenta.